# Why \n does not work in Log.Info method?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, string-formatting

The \n in the String.Format method below within the Log.Info prints "\n" as a text instead of starting a new line; why it does not work? Any idea? How can I make it work?

```
Log.Info(String.Format("Some arguments : \n Since : {0}\nBefore: {1}\nLog file name : {2}", since, before,logFileName));
```

Thanks!

Comment: A, sorry, I thought you would consider the Log4Net in the tag list.

Comment: My apologies, I somehow missed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On windows, the line feed is actually `\r\n`. Try `Environment.NewLine`:

```
Log.Info(String.Format("Some arguments : "+Environment.NewLine+" Since : {0}"+Environment.NewLine+"Before: {1}"+Environment.NewLine+"Log file name : {2}", since, before,logFileName));
```

Comment: From which package does "Environment" come from?